# Require() is undefined after transpiling with Babel?

Tags: javascript, gulp

This is my gulp task, and I have a few 'require()' statements in my source js file. Since I do Babel, why is my browser still saying 'require() is undefined' as it should recognize it?

```
gulp.task('reduceSize', function() {
  return gulp.src(source)
    .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['env']
    }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename('bundle.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});
```

Comment: babel doesn't "transpile" require

Comment: where are you running this task?